# Webpack for react configuration issue

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, jsx

I have a problem with the configuration of webpack. The error happened when I installed the dependencies "react react-dom"

According to my search everything has to be fine, but certainly not.

The error is the following:

```
Hash: f2d1526b060b4c79da6f
Version: webpack 3.11.0
Time: 342ms
     Asset       Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
    app.js     2.8 kB       0  [emitted]  main
index.html  353 bytes          [emitted]
   [0] multi ./src/index.jsx 28 bytes {0} [built]
   [1] ./src/index.jsx 206 bytes {0} [built] [failed] [1 error]

ERROR in ./src/index.jsx
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (7:6)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|   render(){
|     return(
|       <h1>Ar</h1>
|     )
|   }
 @ multi ./src/index.jsx
Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
     1 asset
       [0] ./node_modules/html-webpack-                
plugin/lib/loader.js!./src/assets/index.html 690 bytes {0} [built]
       [2] (webpack)/buildin/global.js 509 bytes {0} [built]
       [3] (webpack)/buildin/module.js 517 bytes {0} [built]
```

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: please share your webpack config, package.json and .babelrc if possible

Comment: I already share it in a comment, because I could not put it in the original question

Comment: sorry missed, check my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install `npm i -D babel-core`;

and

try:

```
module: {
        rules: [
            {test: /\.jsx?$/, exclude: /node_modules/, use: ["babel-loader"]},
            {test: /\.css$/, use: ["style-loader", `css-loader?${cssModules}`}
        ]
    }
```

Comment: C:\webpack.config.js:21
                    {test: /\.jsx?$/, exclude: /node_modules/, "babel-loader"},
        SyntaxError: Unexpected token }
            at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
            at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
            at Module._compile (module.js:607:28)
            at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
            at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
            at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
            at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)

Comment: I still get this error:
    {test: /\.jsx?$/, exclude: /node_modules/, "babel-loader"},                                                                                                                      
                                                                                           ^                                                                                                                                                                      SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

Comment: It's the old version, so you forgot to save and rerun webpack. Double check pls.